# Неправильный поиск одинаковых значений из одной коллекции в другой

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, динамические-массивы

Имеется `TreeSet<Integer> scores = new TreeSet<>(Collections.reverseOrder());` содержащий следующие значения:

3 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -1000

Эти значения должны сравниваться со значеними в `ArrayList<Integer> unsorted = new ArrayList<>();`

[**-4**, 0, 4, 1, 0, **-1**, 0, 4, 1, 1, **-3**, 0, 4, 1, 2, **-2**, 0, 4, 2, 0, **0**, 0, 4, 2, 2, **-4**, 0, 4, 3, 0, **-3**, 0, 0, 1, 0, **-1000**, 0, 1, 1, 0, **3**, 0, 1, 1, 1, **-1000**, 0, 1, 1, 2, **0**, 0, 2, 1, 1]

находящимися в позициях по индексам, кратным 5, и затем эти индексы должны быть добавлены в `ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();` с помощью вот такого кода:

```java
for (Integer i : scores) {
    for (int j = 0; j < unsorted.size(); j = j + 5) {
        if ((i.intValue() == unsorted.get(j).intValue()) & j % 5 == 0) {
            indices.add(unsorted.indexOf(unsorted.get(j).intValue()));
        }
    }
}
out.println(indices.toString());
```

Однако на выходе получаю список индексов

[28, 1, 1, 5, 15, 10, 10, 0, 0, 35, 35]

вместо ожидаемого

[40, 20, 50, 5, 15, 10, 30, 0, 25, 35, 45]

Выглядит так, как будто внутренний цикл идёт почему-то с шагом +1 (хотя задан +5); кроме того, по идее, при нахождении повторяющихся значений должны быть добавлены номера всех индесков, а не только первого, где значение встретилось, т.к. команды break; при выполнении условия внутреннего цикла нет, и, допустим, для значения -1000 после нахождения индеска первой позиции итерация должна продолжаться...

Comment: `if (i.intValue()==unsorted.get(j).intValue()){ indices.add(j); }`

Comment: Точно, теперь работает как надо, спасибо! А то я перемудрил что-то...